# JSON jQuery Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter

So I'm trying out JSON for the first time. I have this Twitter API feed that I'm trying to output. Just curious to where I'm going wrong. Attached is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol class="result"></ol>
    <script>
      $.getJSON('http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1105779.json', function(json) {
        alert(json.trends.query[1]);
        $('.result').html('<li>' + json.trends.query + '</li>');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
<!-- http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1105779.json -->
```

Comment: And I'm curious to know what your problem is?

Comment: That URL doesn't return a JSON string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the URL to `'http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1105779.json?callback=?'`.

Your request needs to be JSONP'ed to work around the XHR policy restrictions.

If the URL includes something similar to `callback=?` jQuery does its magic to make the request a JSONP request. For more on this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are trying to access `query` as if it were an array. It's not, it's an object. `trends` is the actual array. So if you wanted the `query` property of the second object in the `trends` array, which is what it appears you are trying to do, you'd do this:

```
var query = json.trends[1].query;
```

EDIT:

If you are, as a commenter suggests, trying to access the *first* element in the `trends` array, it is at array index `0`. So:

```
var query = json.trends[0].query;
```

Your second statement, `json.trends.query` is also invalid because `trends` is an array, not an object, and has no property `query`. If your objective is to get each `query` property from all the objects in the `trends` array, use jQuery's [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) looping construct. Like so:

```
$.each(json.trends, function(i, result) {
     $('.result').append(result.query);
});
```

You also need to add `callback=?` to the end of your query string you pass to [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). jQuery replaces the `?` with a randomly generated function name, which allows jQuery to call your callback function and pass it the data. This implements a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) request, which is not subject to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Putting it all together:

```
  $.getJSON('http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1105779.json?callback=?', function(json) {
    alert(json.trends[1].query);
    $.each(json.trends, function(i, result) {
       $('.result').append(result.query);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Seems like it should be `json[0].trends` (at least with chrome)

Comment: No...I answered it as he posted it. Accessing the *second* element in the array, which is at index `1`.

Comment: Thank you for your Advice. I see my errors now. I am however getting a error in chrome console:

1105779.json:-1Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type application/json.

twitter.html:10Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: the extended error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
(anonymous function)twitter.html:10
jQuery.extend.handleSuccessjquery-1.4.4.js:6170
jQuery.extend.ajax.windowjquery-1.4.4.js:5820
(anonymous function)1105779.json:1

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the json returned by the url you gave, you need this:

```
alert(json.trends[1].query);
```

`trends` is a list of objects, each of which has `query` key.